# JavaFX PieChart hide label if value is 0

Tags: javafx, pie-chart

Using `pieChart.setLabelLineLength()`, I am able to set the line's length which also displays the pie's value. But is there any way i can hide this line and label if the value is 0?

```
PieChart pieChart = new PieChart();
pieChart.setData(data);
pieChart.setLabelLineLength(20);
```

Edit: Removing the data from the chart is a way but i wish to retain it in the legends to show the existence of this data, but only to hide the label and line if it's 0 since there's no point in showing it and it creates clutter. Removing the data would remove it from the legends. Is there a way i can remove a particular label/line programmatically?

Comment: if simply setting the length to 0 doesn't hide the label (which I suspect is the gist of your question :), remove the data from the chart?

Comment: can i set individual node's label line length? Because "pieChart.setLabelLineLength(0)" will affect the entire chart which isn't what i want. Also removing the data from the chart will remove it from the legends as well which isn't what i want either, i only wanna hide that particular pie's label if it's value is 0.

Comment: no, not supported - you'll have to implement it yourself. Personally, I would consider it bad UX to have something in the legend that I can't find in the chart, though.

Comment: Hmm.. That is true too.. I am still trying to figure out what is the best way to do this.. The reason i do not wish to remove data is because one, the user may want to see what are the available data, and secondly, i am styling individual pie color using css, by removing a data from the pie would cause the pie to display colors incorrectly, since specific data have specific colors.